# simplifying $ e^{iape^{it}} $

Tags: complex-analysis

For $ t \in [0,\pi] $,
Why does this equality hold
$$
e^{iap\cdot e^{it}} = e^{iap(\cos(t) + i\sin(t))}=e^{-ap\sin(t)}
$$
Specifically, I don't know how to go from the second equality to the third equality.

Comment: This is not true

Comment: what about the variables?

Comment: $ a \in \Re \space and \space p>0 $

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \exp (iape^{it}) &= \exp [iap(\cos t+i\sin t)] \\
  &= \exp [-ap\sin t+iap\cos t] \\
  &= e^{-ap\sin t}e^{iap\cos t} \\
  &= e^{-ap\sin t}[\cos (ap\cos t)+i\sin (ap\cos t)]
\end{align*}

Comment: why does $e^{iap cos(t)} = 1 $

Comment: No, $$e^{iap\cos t}= \cos (ap\cos t)+i\sin (ap\cos t)$$

Comment: so the equality is wrong?

Comment: Very likely, double check your raw materials.